# Update UITableView after server returns for query

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a query to the server with a callback block.

```
- (NSArray *)products{
    if(! _products) {
        [self.query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
            if(! error) {
                _products = objects;
                [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
        }];
    }
    return _products;
}
```

In the same `UITableViewController.m`, I have the following methods implemented:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {}

- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}
```

All these methods used `self.products` somewhere.
I want the table to be updated and show up after the query returns from the server. Before that, I want an activity indicator view to show the user that the data is still being downloaded from the server.
I have tried [self.tableView reloadData] and [self.setNeedsDisplay]. But my table now is still empty.
What am I doing wrong here and how shall I change the code?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are all the methods empty as above, or did you just not show the code?  In any case, you need to set the returned data in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: They are not empty. I did not paste the code for implementation.

Comment: That's where your problem likely is -- reloadData will call cellForRowAtIndexPath for each cell, and you have to supply the updated data in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are reloading it on backgroud update code like this

```
(NSArray *)products{
    if(! _products) {
        [self.query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
            if(! error) {
                _products = objects;
               //reload on main tread
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData]; });
            }
        }];
    }
    return _products;
}
```

Comment: If you are using [obj products]; call somewhere and again reloading data. Then it will return wrong value. When using block products method returns immediately but fetching will perform after some time in background. Try to put log before return and in if(! error)